# Weighted Average w/ Array Formula & Query That Pulls From A Separate Sheet

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-query

[Link To Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bmVkGbfMrbtEMCHhzgX96SHV4IujKvbntaSqNUORnbU/edit#gid=1489095038)

So I've got an array formula which I've included below. I need to adjust this so that it becomes a weighted average based on variables stored on a sheet titled Variables.

Current Formula:

```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(
      {PROPER(ADP!A3:A),ADP!E3:S;
       PROPER(ADP!J3:J),ADP!S3:S;
       PROPER(ADP!Z3:Z),ADP!AG3:AG},
      "select Col1, Sum(Col2)
       where 
        Col2 is not null and
        Col1 is not null
       group by Col1
       order by Sum(Col2)
       label
        Col1 'PLAYER',
        Sum(Col2) 'ADP AVG'"))
```

Here's what I *thought* would work but doesn't:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(
      {PROPER(ADP!A3:A),ADP!E3:E*(Variables!$F$11/Variables!$F$14);
       PROPER(ADP!J3:J),ADP!S3:S*(Variables!$F$12/Variables!$F$14);
       PROPER(ADP!Z3:Z),ADP!AG3:AG*(Variables!$F$13/Variables!$F$14)},
  "select Col1, Sum(Col2)
   where 
    Col2 is not null and
    Col1 is not null
   group by Col1
   order by Sum(Col2)
   label
    Col1 'PLAYER',
    Sum(Col2) 'ADP AVG'"))
```

What I'm trying to get is the value pulled in K to be multiplied by the value in VariablesF11, the value pulled in Y to be multiplied by VariablesF12, and the value in AL multiplied by the variables in F13. And have that numerator divided by the value in VariablesF14.

Comment: Sure @kirkg13 

- here's a copy of the doc. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VUTdh6FMYrs4SL1bhNIVIDrgoSXBbZMxBkd-_RAuSP8/edit?usp=sharing

The variables in question are on the variable sheet under # of Drafts and the array in question is in the GLobalAVG sheet in cell B2

Comment: I'm not quite sure what error you were getting with your formula.  I've added two columns to your GlobalAVG tab - here is a link to the new cell, GlobalAVG!D2, with the formula.  It seems to work fine, doesn't it?  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VUTdh6FMYrs4SL1bhNIVIDrgoSXBbZMxBkd-_RAuSP8/edit#gid=58935708&range=D2

Comment: Hey thanks!
So here's the problem (i *think* but again you will know better than i).
      `{PROPER(ADP!A3:A),ADP!E3:E*(Variables!$F$11/Variables!$F$14); PROPER(ADP!J3:J),ADP!S3:S*(Variables!$F$11/Variables!$F$14); PROPER(ADP!Z3:Z),ADP!AG3:AG*(Variables!$F$11/Variables!$F$14)}`

So the variables are all pulling from F11 but one of them needs to pull from F12 and the other from F13. when that happens - the formula breaks.

Comment: @kirkg13 Regarding that suggested adjustment in C2 - i did try what you said but doesn't seem to fix the problem.... that said, since the entire table is from A to AH, is there an advantage to selecting fewer columns?

Comment: hey - appologies! i see that i didn't clarify in my original post. So I added in a "manual" test in F - that is the expected result for D'Andre Swift. i did try putting in hard numbers but with no luck. Also, I updated the formula in D2 with where i would expect F12 and F13 to be and you can see it radically changed the information found below.

Understood on the VLOOKUP stuff - that makes a lot of sense and works now!

Comment: @kirkg13 Please avoid giving the solution in comments. Instead, write a proper answer so others can be helped as well.

Comment: I'd love to have an answer, but I still haven't found, or perhaps not understood, the problem.  My comments have been intended to gain more understanding of the issue, except for addressing an unrelated error.  Back to the issue - the number you calculate "directly" for D'Andre Swift, "5.38..." is the same value your formula is giving for him down in cell E42.  Everything I see says your formula is working correctly, but you say it isn't .  To me it just seems that the numbers aren't what you expect, but I don't see any error in the formula - UNLESS your formula logic is wrong.

Comment: yeah, i don't think the other guy read what you have said. you're just talking with me.

My logic needs some more flushing out b/c the formula is working but it's not the formula i need to be using. I created a couple of more test formulas just to make sure. So here's the problem as I see it. If someone only appears in ADP!Z3:Z they are going to have unreasonably low averages.... essentially they need to appear in at least 1 of the other data sets for their numbers to be "useful".

Comment: But I can see this being really complicated to figure out and as the data sets change ... those numbers in Variables!F11:F13 could change quite a bit. So the variables tell us how many drafts make up the respective datasets found in ADP table.

Comment: But I can see this being really complicated to figure out and as the data sets change. So maybe you have an idea on this .... hypothetically, I could add as many tables to ADP as I want. The numbers in Variables F11,F12,F13 represent the total number of drafts making up each ADP table respectively. So currently, because F13 is so low AND because some of the players ONLY appear in those data sets, when you run the averages - their numbers are obscenely low. How do i not have these guys who only appear in >.05% included?

Comment: InStackOfHelp, added a Notes tab to your sheet.  Check it out.  But no answer yet on getting the weighting right for your formula.

Comment: thanks! would you prefer i communicate there for now? :-)

Comment: added comments there :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After our extensive chat, I'm providing here the answer we came up with, just on the chance it might somehow help someone else.  But the issue in your case was less about the technicalities of the formula, and more about the structuring of multiple data sources, and the associated logic to pull the data together.

Here is the main formula:

```
={"Adjusted 
Ranking
by " & Variables!F21;
arrayformula(
if(A2:A<>"",
  (  if(((D2:D>0) * Source1Used),D2:D,Variables!$F$21)*Variables!$F$12
   + if(((F2:F>0) * Source2Used),F2:F,Variables!$F$21)*Variables!$F$13
   + if(((H2:H>0) * Source3Used),H2:H,Variables!$F$21)*Variables!$F$14 
   + if(((J2:J>0) * Source4Used),J2:J,Variables!$F$21)*Variables!$F$15 
   + if(((L2:L>0) * Source5Used),L2:L,Variables!$F$21)*Variables!$F$16 
   + if(((N2:N>0) * Source6Used),N2:N,Variables!$F$21)*Variables!$F$17 )) / Variables!$F$18) }
```

A2:A is the list of players' names.  The `D2:D>0` is a test of whether that player has a rating obtained from a particular data source.

`Source1Used` is a named range for a tickbox cell, where the user can indicate whether that data source is to be included in the calculations.

This formula creates an average value, using from 1 to 6 possible sources, user selectable.

The formula that gave the rating value for one specific source is as follows:

```
={"Rating in
Source1";ArrayFormula(if(A2:A<>"",if(C2:C,vlookup(A2:A,indirect("ADP!$" & ADP!E3 & "$10:" & ADP!E5),ADP!E6-ADP!E4+1,0),0),""))}
```

This takes a name in column A, checks if it is listed in a specific source's data, and if so, it pulls back the rating value from the data source.  `INDIRECT` is used since the column locations for each data source may vary, but are obtained from a fixed table, in cells ADP!E3 and E5.  E4 and E6 are the numeric values of the column letters.

[image]